# What is the best way for refactoring excel formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumproduct

Like I ask in title, what is the best way to write formula like this one below. I want sum from all sheets values for Germany (values are in B column)

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(--(First!A2:A11="Germany"),(First!B2:B11)), SUMPRODUCT(--(Second!A2:A11="Germany"),(Second!B2:B11)), SUMPRODUCT(--(Third!A2:A11="Germany"),(Third!B2:B11)))
```

What is your opinion?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. That is good solution.

Answer (score 2):

**In Google Sheets** you can also use

```
=QUERY({L1:M9;O3:P7}, 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 ='xxx' label sum(Col2) 'Total' ",1)
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

**How the formula works.**

We create an array using curly brackets `{}` stacking the ranges one on top of the other using semi-columns `;` even from other sheets like `{L1:M9;O3:P7;First!A2:B11;Second!A2:B11}`. One can add as many ranges as needed. Even open ranges.
The `,1` in the end of the formula shows that the very first row will be treated as a header row.

Please read more about the [**QUERY**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343). function

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: And this does multiple sheets?  The OP is doing 3 sheets

Comment: As many as you want. You can even use open ranges :)

Comment: The idea is that the OP wants a single formula to look at three sheets and add the values in one column where "Germany" exists in another.  While this shows an alternative to SUMIF() which is much shorter and more concise.  It does not show how one could expand this to look at threes sheets in the same formula.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER({First!B2:B11; Second!B2:B11}, 
            {First!A2:A11; Second!A2:A11}="Germany"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({First!A2:A9;Second!A2:A9}="Germany")*{First!B2:B9;Second!B2:B9})
```

[image]